# Split a dictionary on separate dictionaries by keys and assign unique names

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
d = {'jack': {'age':35, 'status': 'single'}, 
'stephan': {'age':27, 'status': 'married'},
'anna': {'age':29, 'status': 'married'},
'max': {'age':37, 'status': 'single'}}
```

My eventual goal is to split it on 4 separate dictionaries by a key and name each of these dictionaries with a unique name like:

```
a = {'jack': {'age':35, 'status': 'single'}}
b = {'stephan': {'age':27, 'status': 'married'}}
c = {'anna': {'age':29, 'status': 'married'}}
e = {'max': {'age':37, 'status': 'single'}}
```

I have a function that splits a dict by keys and returns a list of dictionaries:

```
def split_dict_equally(input_dict, chunks=4):
# prep with empty dicts
return_list = [dict()] * chunks
idx = 0
for k,v in input_dict.items():
    return_list[idx][k] = v
    if idx < chunks-1:  # indexes start at 0
        idx += 1
    else:
        idx = 0
return return_list
```

but this is not exactly what I want.
Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: The dictionary you've shown is not valid syntax.

Comment: What use is that to you? I mean, a dictionary with just one key in it, is a bit ... overkill, no? Maybe you should explain what your overall aim is.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye it\s a nested dictionary you are right, I've edited the code, thanx

Comment: @trincot I will push each of dictionaries into a NoSQL database (CouchDB) as a single document

Comment: @Ekaterina Still invalid :/ Pls, try it out on a terminal before posting.

Comment: @moseskoledoye fixed it, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Transform the dict into a list of dicts
people = [{k: v} for k, v in original_dict.iteritems()]
# Unpack the first 4 elements of the list into 4 new variables
a, b, c, e = people[:4]
```

Comment: could you please add an explanation about what your code does?

Answer (score 1):

Modify you dictionary to this:

```
d = {'jack': {'age':35, 'status': 'single'}, #seems more intuitive
'stephan': {'age':27, 'status': 'married'},
'anna': {'age':29, 'status': 'married'},
'max': {'age':37, 'status': 'single'}}
#print
a={}
b={}
a['jack']=d['jack']
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write a small function to create new independent dicts like so:

```
def func(dct):
   names = ('jack', 'stephan', 'anna', 'max')
   return [{k: dct[k].copy()} for k in names]

a, b, c, d = func(dct)
print(a)
# {'jack': {'status': 'single', 'age': 35}}
```

If you want to use the same dicts nested in the main dict, then you won't need to `copy`.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more why is copy needed in this case? didn't understand the above written explanation.

Comment: @akp If you modify one of the nested dicts in `a`, `b`, `c` or `d`, the changes will be seen in the original large dict `dct`, since the inner dict objects are the same. `copy` creates new copies of the inner dicts.

Comment: But `.copy()` is shallow copy which means that any changes will be reflected. How it helps?

Comment: @akp You only need a shallow copy here since the inner dicts have no dicts nested within themselves. And no, changes won't be reflected.